# If $a_{1}=1$ and $a_{n+1}=1+\frac{n}{a_{n}}$, then $a_{n}=\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{8\sqrt{n}}+o\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, approximation

let sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ such $$a_{1}=1,a_{n+1}=1+\dfrac{n}{a_{n}}$$

show that:
$$a_{n}=\sqrt{n}+\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{1}{8\sqrt{n}}+o\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)?$$

Comment: You could approximate the difference equation with a differential equation and find a solution in terms of a series in powers of $\sqrt{n}$ with an ansatz.

Comment: @orion. Could you please elaborate for me ? I am very interested by what you seem to propose but I don't know how to handle it. Thanks.

Comment: This result is china student creat it" I doubt that (unless Don Knuth is "a chinese student").

Answer (score 15):

I will present two approaches to this question. The first is less advanced and easier but also yields a less optimal result.

---

### First Method

Consider
 the auxiliary sequence $b_n =\sqrt{n+\frac{1}{4}}+\frac{1}{2}$. This is
 the unique positive solution to the $P_n(X)=0$ where $P_n(X)=X^2-X-n$.

> ${\bf Lemma~1.}$ For every $n\geq1$, we have
>   $b_{n+1}\geq 1+\dfrac{n}{b_{n-1}}$.

*Proof*. Indeed, let $u=1+\frac{n}{b_{n-1}}$ then
$$u^2-u=\frac{(n+b_{n-1})n}{b_{n-1}^2}=\frac{(n+b_{n-1})n}{b_{n-1}+n-1}=
n+\frac{n}{b_{n-1}+n-1}\leq n+1$$
since $b_{n-1}\geq 1$. This shows that $P_{n+1}(u)\leq0$ and 
consequently $u\leq b_{n+1}$ as desired.$\qquad \square$

> ${\bf Lemma~2.}$ For every $n\geq1$, we have
>   $b_{n-1}\leq a_n \leq b_n$.

*Proof*. This is now an easy induction. Clearly true for $n=1$, and if 
it is true for some $n$ then
$$
b_n=1+\frac{n}{b_n}\leq 1+\frac{n}{a_n}\leq 1+\frac{n}{b_{n-1}}\leq 
b_{n+1}.
$$
and the result follows.$\qquad \square$

It follows that
$$
\sqrt{n-\frac{3}{4}}-\sqrt{n}\leq a_n-\sqrt{n}-\frac{1}{2}\leq \sqrt{n+\frac{1}{4}}-\sqrt{n}
$$
Thus
$$\sqrt{n}\left\vert a_n-\sqrt{n}-\frac{1}{2}\right\vert\leq \frac{3}{4(1+\sqrt{1-3/(4n)})}\leq \frac{1}{2}$$
So, we have proved that, for every $n\geq 1$ we have
$$
a_n= \sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{2}+{\cal O} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)
$$
This is not the desired expansion but it has the merit to be easy to prove.

---

### Second Method

The general reference in this part is the book of D. Knuth. "[The art of Computer programming, Vol III](http://books.google.com/books?id=ePzuAAAAMAAJ&q=The%20art%20of%20Computer%20programming,%20Vol%203&dq=The%20art%20of%20Computer%20programming,%20Vol%203&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VyVRU86ACcm1PKr0gdAE&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBg), second edition, pp.63--65".

Let $I(n)$ be the number of involutions  in the symmetric group $S_n$, ($i.e.$ $\sigma\in S_n$ such that $\sigma^2=I$). It is well-known that $I(n)$ can be calculated inductively by
$$
I(0)=I(1)=1,\qquad I(n+1)=I(n)+nI(n-1) 
$$
This shows that our sequence $\{a_n\}$ is related to these numbers by the formula
$$a_n=\frac{I(n+1)}{I(n)}.$$

So, we can use what we know about these numbers, In particular, the following asymptotic expansion, from Knuth's book:
$$
I(n+1)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} n^{n/2}e^{-n/2+\sqrt{n}-1/4}\left(1+\frac{7}{24\sqrt{n}}+{\cal O}\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/4}}\right)\right).
$$
Now, it is a "simple" matter to conclude from this that $a_n$ has the desired asymptotic expansion.

**Edit:** In fact the term $\mathcal{O}(n^{-3/4})$ effectively destroys the asymptotic expansion as [mercio](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/17445/mercio) noted, But in fact we have 
$$
I(n+1)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} n^{n/2}e^{-n/2+\sqrt{n}-1/4}\left(1+\frac{7}{24\sqrt{n}}+{\cal O}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right).
$$
This is shown by WIMP AND ZEILBERGER in their paper ``Resurrecting the Asymptotics
of Linear Recurrences'', that can be found [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X85902094).

Comment: doesn't the $O(n^{-3/4})$ prevent us from seeing the wanted $-1/8\sqrt n$ term ?

Comment: @mercio, you are right, thank you, but this can be saved.

Answer (score 2):

It will be simpler in what follows to use two steps at once, so we can start by computing the relationship $a_{n+2} = \frac{a_n(n+2) + n}{a_n + n}$, and letting $b_n = a_n / \sqrt n$ we get $b_{n+2} = \frac {b_n (1 + 2/n) + 1/\sqrt n}{b_n\sqrt{1/n+2/n^2} + \sqrt{1+2/n}}$.

Let's denote $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} x = \frac {ax+b}{cx+d}$.
If we have a relation $b_{n+2} = \begin{bmatrix} 1+A & B \\ C & 1+D \end{bmatrix} b_n$ where each $A,B,C,D$ is an $O(1/\sqrt n)$ and we look then at some $c_n = (b_n-k)\sqrt n$, we obtain on the sequence $c_n$ the same kind of relation (so with dominant term still begin $I_2$) with
$$A' = (1+A-kC)\sqrt{1+2/n}-1, \\B' = (B-kD+kA-k^2C)\sqrt{n+2}, \\
C' = C/\sqrt n, \\ D' = D+kC$$.

Right now, $C$ is still as big as everyone else, so to make $B'$ not an order of magnitude bigger than the rest, we have to solve a degree $2$ equation in $k$, which gives $k= \pm 1$.

If we define $c_n = (b_n-1)\sqrt n$, we get $A' = -n^{-1/2} + O(n^{-1}), D' = +n^{-1/2} + O(n^{-1}), C' = O(n^{-1}), B' = O(n^{-1/2})$.

From now $C'$ will continue to plummet, the dominant terms of $A'$ and $D'$ will not be able to change, and so to make the next $B$ into an $O(n^{-1/2})$ term, we will have to pick $k = $ the constant term of $B/(A-D)$.

What this tells us is that there are exactly two asymptotic developments for $a_n$ whose error terms at each level obey a recurrent relation of the form $r_{n+2} = [I_2 + O(n^{-1/2})] r_n$.

Since all of this can be done algebraically, those two power series are $\sqrt n$ times the two solutions in $\Bbb Q[[n^{-1/2}]]$ to the original equation on $a_n/\sqrt n$ (and you go from one to the other by switching the sign of $\sqrt n$).

Now we can look at $u_n = ((((a_n/\sqrt n - 1)\sqrt n - \frac 12)\sqrt n + \frac 18)\sqrt n + \frac 18)\sqrt n$.
It satisfies $u_{n+2} = \begin{bmatrix}1 - n^{-1/2} + O(n^{-1}) && \frac 7 {64}n^{-1} + O(n^{-3/2}) \\ O(n^{-5/2}) && 1 + n^{-1/2} + O(n^{-1}) \end{bmatrix} u_n$,
(and each constant in those $O$ can be effectively computed)

This means that if you have $u_n$ close enough to $0$, then $u_{n+2} = (1-2n^{-1/2})u_n + O(n^{-1})$. So it should mean that for each bound $\delta$ there is an $n_0$ such that $\forall n > n_0, |u_n < \delta | \implies |u_{n+2} < \delta|$.

If you effectively compute $n_0$ for, say, $\delta = 1$, this allows you to provably check that a sequence $u_n$ stays bounded by finding a term $u_n$ with $n$ large enough that is below the $\delta$. If the asymptotic development is valid, a finite computation will be able to prove it.

---

I would love to see a proof that the asymptotic development is valid for every starting value of $a_n$ (except the one value that will stay away infinitely from the asymptotic formula and will instead obey the other asymptotic development)