# Given the sequence $a_1=1$,$a_{n+1}=1+\frac{n}{a_n}$, does the sequence $a_n+n-a_n^2$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Given the sequence $a_1=1$,$a_{n+1}=1+\frac{n}{a_n}$, does the sequence $a_n+n-a_n^2$ converges? If it converges, find the limit.

Now, I proved
$\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4(n-1)}}{2}\leq a_n\leq \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4n}}{2}$,
and
$0\leq p_n=a_n+n-a_n^2\leq 1,p_{n+1}+\frac{n}{a_n^2}p_n=1$,which implies $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}p_{n+1}=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}p_{n-1}$,
but I cannot prove $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}p_{n+1}=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}p_{n}$ which means the squence $a_n+n-a_n^2$ limit equals to ${1\over2}$

so the question is: how can I prove $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}p_{n+1}=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}p_{n}$ ?

Comment: Note: The limit doesn't seem to be equal to 1/2.

Comment: It's easy to prove $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n}{a_n^2}=1$

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/758900/if-a-1-1-and-a-n1-1-fracna-n-then-a-n-sqrtn-frac12) might help.

Comment: Ah, extending out the series much further, it might be possible that the limit is 1/2. $p_{1000} \approx 0.5078$ and converges really slowly.

Comment: Mathematica?It seems 1023 is the recurrence limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like my following solution. By giving it, I just want to tell to others that this sequence is indeed convergent (contradicting to what I'm used to think).
I'm still looking forward to seeing other approaches to this question.

**Lemma**(Some sort of controlled time series)
Let $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ be two real sequence such that:

- $\lim_{n \rightarrow+ \infty} a_n= \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} b_n= 0$
- $a_n \ge 0$ and $ \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n =+\infty$

Then for any sequence $(q_n)$ such that:
$$ q_{n+1}=q_n+a_n( b_n-q_n)$$
we have: $$\lim q_n=0$$
$\square$

Back to our main question

**Main solution**( If your work is true)

We have :
$$ p_{n+1}=1-\frac{n}{a_n^2}p_n=1-\frac{n}{a_n^2}(1-\frac{n-1}{a_{n-1}^2}p_{n-1})=\frac{n(n-1)}{a_n^2a_{n-1}^2}p_{n-1}+(1-\frac{n}{a_n^2})$$
Thus by choosing:

- $r_n:=p_{n}-\frac{1}{2}$
- $c_n:=1-\frac{n(n-1)}{a_n^2a_{n-1}^2}$
- $d_n:= \dfrac{1-\frac{n}{a_n^2} }{1-\frac{n(n-1)}{a_n^2a_{n-1}^2}}-\frac{1}{2}$

We have:

- $r_{n+1}= r_{n-1}-c_n( d_n-r_{n-1})$
- $\lim c_n= \lim d_n= 0$
- $c_n \ge 0$ and $\sum_{k} c_{2k} = \sum_{k} c_{2k+1}=+\infty$

(Note that:  $1- \frac{n}{a_n^2} \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$)
From which, we apply my lemma at the very beginning for two sequence $(r_{2n})$ and $(r_{2n-1})$.
Hence, we have the conclusion that :
$$ \lim p_n=\frac{1}{2}$$
$\square$

**Comments**

- Though my solution is not complicated, this question **should** not be this complicated.
- I think this question is a simple one until I have to manually craft a  lemma for it.
- It would be nice if Mr.Grape can extend my knowledge by telling me where did you find this question.
- I'm still looking forward to nicer solution.

**Updated comment**
Oh, so this question is not a simple question. And so my lemma provides a general method to deal with this kind of question and even proves (apparently) the convergence when $a_0$ arbitrary. (which is some bit more general than the newled provided link)

Comment: Impressive prove and nice lemma! The sequence $d_n$ seems the essential of the limit,I would like to check it.

Comment: $p_{n+1}-p_{n}=(a_{n+1}-a_n)+1-(a_{n+1}^2-a_n^2)=1+(a_{n+1}-a_n)(1-(a_{n+1}+a_n))$$=1-(1+\frac{n}{a_n}-a_n)(\frac{n}{a_n}+a_n)=1-p_n(1-\frac{n}{a_n^2})\\$, $\\p_{n+1}+\frac{n}{a_n^2}p_n=1$

Answer (score 2):

- **Link with the number of involutions in the symmetric goup $S_n$**.
  Let $I_0=1$. Let, for $n\geqslant 1$, $I_n$ be the number of involutions in the symmetric group $S_n$ (i.e $\ \sigma \in S_n \ | \ \sigma^2=I$). We can show that $\ I_1=1 \ $ , and $\ \forall n \in \mathbb N^{\star} \ , \ I_{n+1}=I_n+nI_{n-1}$. And, by induction, $\ \forall n\in \mathbb N \ , \ a_n=\frac{I_{n+1}}{I_n}\  $ .
- **L Moser and M Wyman, On solutions of x^d=1 in symmetric groups, Canad. J. Math., 7 (1955)**  This paper can be found [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/on-solutions-of-xd-1-in-symmetric-groups/8F90642D9472FA7326164E54BE3BE57B) . In this article, it is shown that exists $(\beta_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that $\ \forall p \in \mathbb N \ , \ a_n =\sqrt{n} +\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^p \dfrac{\beta_k}{n^{k/2}}+{\rm o}\left(\dfrac{1}{n^{p/2}}\right)\ $. For example $\ a_n=\sqrt{n}+\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{1}{8\sqrt{n}} +{\rm o}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$. With that  result, it's easy to show that $\ \lim (a_n+n-a_n^2)=\dfrac{1}{2}$ .
- If $\ b_0 \in \mathbb R_+^{\star}\ $ and $\ \forall n \in \mathbb N \ , \ b_{n+1}=1+\frac{n}{b_n} \ $, then, $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ has the same asymptotic expansion: $\ \forall p \in \mathbb N \ , \ a_n =\sqrt{n} +\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^p \dfrac{\beta_k}{n^{k/2}}+{\rm o}\left(\dfrac{1}{n^{p/2}}\right)\ $. (the same coefficients $\beta_k$ )

Comment: It's great to know more. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.